# Create Ads from published page post in Facebook

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ads-api

I want to create Ads by using Facebook Published page post. For this process, I'm able to get all Published Posts of a Page through graph API (page_id/posts). Also, I can create ad creative along with the Post_Id. However, When I use this created ad_creative id in the Ad creation process, it through this error "Invalid parameter: Ad Creative Does Not Use Valid Link." 
For Doc... references: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/ad-creative#obtaining_pp    Also for generating the ad, I used this method.
  ad = ad_account.ads.create({
         name: ' Ad* via Post',
        adset_id: under_adset_id,
        creative: {
          creative_id: post_creative_id,
        },
        status: 'PAUSED',
      })

Answer (score 0):

Add 'link' field to request

```
creative: { creative_id: post_creative_id, link: "https://stackoverflow.com/"},
```